# I cannot click in the input field, only the title

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, input

For some reason I cannot edit the input field on my site (WordPress). I should be able to click in the form field and add the email address, but it only works when I click on the title element.

Here is the test site: http://teetaku.hu/teszt-form/

If I change the template to the default version, it works :/

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: There is an element lying on top of your input field. That stops you from clicking on the input. Just remove that and you'le be fine

Comment: It is generated by a Visual Composer add-on, so I gues I cannot delete it. I Tried using: display:none!important, now it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a span on top of your input field. You can focus on the input field if you simply remove the code below:

```
<span class="dhvc-form-add-on"><i class="None"></i></span>
   <i class="None"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: It is generated by a Visual Composer add-on, so I gues I cannot delete it. I Tried using: display:none!important, now it works...